A result of Tornehave about tom Dieck's homomorphism
Let $G$ be a (finite) $2$-group and let $A(G)$ denote the Burnside ring of $G$, i.e. the Grothendieck ring of $G$-set. Tornehave proved in 1984 (see here) that every unit in $A(G)$ is orthogonal, i.e. under the identification $A(G)^\times \cong \omega^0_G$, every unit is represented by an element in $C_{O(V)}(G)$ for some real representation $V$ (I'm not 100% sure what "represented" means, honestly). In the computation explicitly, he introduces $N(G)$, the kernel of the linearization homomorphism $A(G) \to R_\mathbb{R}(G)$, shows elements of $N(G)$ determine elements of $KO^{-1}_G(\ast)$, and uses the equivariant $j$-homomorphism $KO^{-1}_G(\ast)\to \omega^0_G \cong A(G)^\times$.
However nowadays, this result is reframed as stating instead that the tom Dieck homomorphism $\Theta: RO(G) \to A(G)^\times, V\mapsto ( H \mapsto (-1)^{\dim(V^H)})$ is surjective. Tracing through tom Dieck's Representation Theory text (starting at page 105, much of the same proof is traced out more concisely), he states that instead, $KO^{-1}_G(\ast)$ can be viewed as the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space with basis given by real irreps of real type, therefore the tom Dieck homomorphism factors through $j: KO^{-1}_G(\ast) \to A(G)^\times$ - this should be identified with the equivariant $j$-homomorphism.
However, I don't understand why the two cases are the same or what an explicit isomorphism would be between these two identifications (and how it would translate for the $j$-homomorphism). Explicitly, given an $[x_+] - [x_-] \in N(G)$, how does one obtain the corresponding real representation in $RO(G)$? (It isn't a linearization $\mathbb{R}x_+ = \mathbb{R}x_-$, this isn't even well-defined)
edit: In short, in tom Dieck's text, Theorem 6.5.6 should imply Theorem 6.5.1, judging by the proof of Proposition 6.5.7. Why is this the case? In particular, how does surjectivity of $U: N(G) \to N(G)^\times$ show $N(G)^\times$ is covered by the tom Dieck homomorphism?
